# Examples for C++20 modules?

Tags: c++, module, c++20, c++-modules

Modules are a big thing in the upcoming C++20. Of course there are differing opinions on whether or not they are great, but I imagine that it will be important to know them in the future. I have watched some talks about modules and read some tutorials, so I think I have a passing understanding on how to use them.

But what I learned was mostly pretty local, i.e. how would I write *one* module. So I am unsure about what a difference modules will make in bigger picture. How will they affect the layout of our libraries and executables and their usage?

Altough I would be grateful if you have some references on this, I am more interested in seeing modules in action. Do you know any examples of projects using modules already? (Preferably medium-sized) It would be perfect to see a before/after comparison of a project changing to using modules, but I am happy with whatever I can get.

Comment: Modules do not affect layout of libraries or executables... at least by default. A module can consist of several libraries - that's the only difference I am aware of. But I doubt that it matters at all, though, it might have weird side effects. However, as far as I know, current experimental modules do not support the multiple-library feature. So there is noway to test it at the moment.

Comment: According to [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), implementing suport of modules is still "In progress".